# RestAPI Deserialization VendAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

I am attempting to call the Vend API through restAPI.

I call make the calls to execute and retrieve the data into Content but when I try to access the deserialized object through the data property, the list of items

var response = client.Execute(request);

I get one entry in the List and the entries are empty/null.

The API is described at https://developers.vendhq.com/documentation/api/0.x/consignments.html

My code for the serialized object is:

```
public class stock_movements : List<Stock_Movement>
{
    public stock_movements()
    {
    }
}

public class Stock_Movement
{
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string type {get; set;}
    public DateTime date {get; set;}
    public string outlet_id {get; set;}
    public string supplier_id {get; set;}
    public string status {get; set;}
    public DateTime received_at {get; set;}
    public DateTime created_at {get; set;}
    public DateTime updated_at {get; set;}

    public List<Product> products { get; set; }

    public Stock_Movement()
    {
    }
}

public class Product
{
        public string id {get; set;}
        public string product_id {get; set;}
        public string name {get; set;}
        public int count {get; set;}
        public int received {get; set;}
        public Decimal cost {get; set;}
        public DateTime created_at {get; set;}
        public DateTime updated_at {get; set;}
}
```

The code to call the API is:

```
    public stock_movements get_StockMovements()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("stock_movements", Method.GET);
        return Execute<stock_movements>(request);
    }

    private T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(Constants.VendAPIBaseURL);

        request.AddParameter("access_token", _auth.access_token, ParameterType.QueryString);

        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);


        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
            var vendException = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
            throw vendException;
        }

        return response.Data;

    }   //  private T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your class `stock_movements` is wrong: The deserializer might expect a class with a list-property instead of an inherited list.

```
// old -> public class stock_movements : List<Stock_Movement>
public class StockMovementsResponse
{
    public IList<Stock_Movement> StockMovements { get; set; }
}
```

And then call:

```
Execute<StockMovementsResponse>(request);
```

Comment: It worked except that I had to define it as List instead of IList to implement the concrete class from the interface.

Thank you so much for your assistance.